# I can`t see my created tables in HSQLDB, what could be the issue?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, hsqldb

My environment is HSQLDB, Maven and spring-boot.
I have created 2 entity POJOs. I do see the `CREATE TABLE` command under `testedb.log` file. But when I open `Data Source Explorer` in Eclipse, I can`t see my tables, albeit I do see all the system tables.

I have looked at this question too, but no vail: [Where can I see the HSQL database and tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240017/where-can-i-see-the-hsql-database-and-tables)

Here is my **partial** pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here is my **partial** `application.properties`:

```
# DataSource
#spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:resources/db/testedb;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:memTestdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

# Hibernate
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

And below is my HSQLDB created on disk:

[HSQLDB folder in my workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDFoq.png)
Here is my  **partial** `testedb.script`:

```
SET FILES LOG SIZE 50
CREATE USER SA PASSWORD DIGEST 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
ALTER USER SA SET LOCAL TRUE
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
CREATE SEQUENCE PUBLIC.HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE AS INTEGER START WITH 1
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.ENQUIRY_HISTORY(ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY  KEY,FROM_AMOUNT DOUBLE NOT NULL,FROM_CURRENCY VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,QUERY_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,TO_AMOUNT DOUBLE NOT NULL,TO_CURRENCY VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,USER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,VERSION INTEGER NOT NULL)
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.USERS(ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,EMAIL VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,LAST_LOGIN TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,VERSION VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)
ALTER SEQUENCE SYSTEM_LOBS.LOB_ID RESTART WITH 1
ALTER SEQUENCE PUBLIC.HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE RESTART WITH 1
SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SQL_IDENTIFIER TO PUBLIC
```

Please see above that the `CREATE TABLE` contains the word **MEMORY** even though I have created **file** DB.

And by `testsdb.log`:

```
/*C12*/SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
drop table enquiry_history if exists
drop table users if exists
drop sequence hibernate_sequence if exists
create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
create table enquiry_history (id bigint not null, from_amount float not null, from_currency varchar(255) not null, query_date timestamp not null, to_amount float not null, to_currency varchar(255) not null, user_id bigint not null, version integer not null, primary key (id))
create table users (id bigint not null, email varchar(255) not null, last_login timestamp not null, password varchar(255) not null, version varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))
/*C14*/SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
DISCONNECT
/*C17*/SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
```

And Finally here is my screen shot of Database 
[Data Source Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkjtG.png)

Any pointer will be awesome, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

`file` and `mem` are `in-process` modes. For testing/debugging, if you need concurrent access to data from another process, start database in `Server` mode.

Check various available modes [here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_access_tools).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to see the tables using in build HSQLDB interface, now a fancy one but it still works for me.
I used the following [listed in this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/35240141/8610216]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35240141/8610216)

```
java -cp /path/to/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager
```

And then specify path your database:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:mydb
```

There was one more thing that I was doing incorrect; it was the path of the db. The correct path is `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:src/main/resources/db/userx;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false`in application.properties.